# Angular.io proxy config

Tags: angular, webpack, proxy

I want to proxy all requests from local `/api/v2` to `https://somedomain.com/api/v2`, I have such proxy js config:

```
{
  "/api/v2/*":
  {
    "target": "https://somedomain.com",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

But this config does not work as I've expected, here is example:
from `/api/v2/some/test` to `https://somedomain.com/api/v2/some/test`

But it seems this does not work correctly, here what I see in console:

```
[HPM] GET /api/v2/some/test -> https://somedomain.com
```

Comment: enable the secure property, `"secure": true`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez changing secure option does not have any affect on this routing

Answer (score 1):

There was no problem at all, just led to misunderstanding that this logs in console `[HPM] GET /api/v2/some/test -> https://somedomain.com`, so this is working ok.